# error in Loop Json from query in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to retrieve information of BD with ajax.
The thing is when i receive the data from the script php, it send me a json file, but i cant print the values, this is my code.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{

    $('table').on("click", "p",  function(){
        let value = $(this).attr('value')
        if (value=='true') {
            $(this).addClass('disabled')
            let data = $(this).attr('data-value')
            var info = {
                "numSelection":data,
                "sort": "97"
            }
            $.ajax({
                data:info,
                url:"js/service.php",
                type:"post",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    console.log("Estamos en proceso con ajax")// Here we are fine
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data)//this print the json file in console 
                                correctly
                $.each(data,function(i,item){//here is the error in console
                    console.log("Index: "+i)
                    console.log("Item: "+item)
                })              

            })          
        }
    });
});
```

in this step i receive this error un console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '957' in + the content of the json file

and this is my php script with the sql

```
<?php 
// var_dump();
// error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
include('conn.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE sorteos_id=".$_POST['sorteo'].";";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$enviar = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $enviar[]=$row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo json_encode($enviar);
?>
```

If I do not send the information in json format, it is sent in an array but with an annoying message

> **Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **C:\UwAmp\www\testing\js\service.php** on line **19**
>       Array

I am new coding so i accept any suggestion

Comment: What does the console log of the data look like?

Comment: post the php if this is related to it also. If not, you need to remove the tag; it's misleading and makes the question unclear.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It was hidden I edited his question

Comment: @MehdiBounya ok thanks; I made a few more minor adjustments and no waiting on another to approve the edit, which makes expedites things a tad. Edit: to which another edit was made by someone else.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search` - did you not Google that error? There are far too many possible duplicates for this.

Comment: looks like you are passing in sort and using sorteo.  which means you are echoing '0 results' which is not json.  have a look at chrome network XHR tab to confirm.

Comment: xeo... youre right, but it was a typing error... i send and reseive sorteo and the console log in .done show me in console the json file with all the result of the mysq query... So i need to show it... but dont know how...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys for trying to help me with this. But they gave me many ideas, so i found my answer...

My mistake was, dont specify what format i am waiting, just have to add
 `dataType: "json` in the  config of `$.ajax`.

```js
$.ajax({
  data: info,
  url: "js/service.php",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json", //this to receive json
  beforeSend: function() {
    console.log("Estamos en proceso con ajax")
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log("Index: " + i)
    console.log("Item: " + item)
  })

})
```

**php**

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $enviar = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $enviar[]=$row;
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo json_encode($enviar);//this to send json
```